# Generate variable length data with Tensorflow ops

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to learn a classifier on audio files. I read my WAV files and convert them to a sequence of spectrogram images for training in a custom Python function. The function is called with `tf.py_func` and returns an array of images with the same shape. In other words the image shape is well defined, yet the number of images is dynamic. (e.g. 3 spectrograms for short audio snippet, 15 for a long snippet)

Is there a way to unpack the resulting list for further processing / enqueueing in `tf.train.batch_join()`? The undefined sequence length seems to be a problem for many TF ops. Can the length be inferred somehow?

```
...
// Read the audio file name and label from a CSV file
audio_file, label = tf.decode_csv(csv_content)

def read_audio(audio_file):

    signal = read_wav(audio_file)
    images = [generate_image(segment) for segment in split_audio(signal)]

    // This output is of varying length depending on the length of audio file.
    return images

// Convert audio file to a variable length sequence of images
// Shape: <unknown>, which is to be expected from tf.py_func
image_sequence = tf.py_func(wav_to_spectrogram, [audio_file], [tf.float32])[0]

// Auxilliary to set a shape for the images defined in tf.py_func
def process_image(in_image):
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(in_image, dtype=tf.float32)
    image.set_shape([600, 39, 1])

    return (image, label)


// Shape: (?, 600, 39, 1)
images_labels = tf.map_fn(process_image, image_sequence, dtype=(tf.float32, tf.int32))


// This will not work. 'images_and_labels' needs to be a list
images, label_index_batch = tf.train.batch_join(
    images_and_labels,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity=2 * num_preprocess_threads * batch_size,
    shapes=[data_shape, []],
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use variable size Tensor as input and `enqueue_many` to treat this tensor as a variable size input batch.

Below is an example of `py_func` generating variable size batches and batch with `enqueue_many` converting it to constant size batches.
[image]

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

# start with time-out to prevent hangs when experimenting
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.operation_timeout_in_ms=2000
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)

# initialize first queue with 1, 2, 1, 2
queue1 = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=4, dtypes=[tf.int32])
queue1_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
queue1_enqueue = queue1.enqueue(queue1_input)
sess.run(queue1_enqueue, feed_dict={queue1_input: 1})
sess.run(queue1_enqueue, feed_dict={queue1_input: 2})
sess.run(queue1_enqueue, feed_dict={queue1_input: 1})
sess.run(queue1_enqueue, feed_dict={queue1_input: 2})
sess.run(queue1.close())

# call_func will produce variable size tensors
def range_func(x):
  return np.array(range(x), dtype=np.int32)
[call_func] = tf.py_func(range_func, [queue1.dequeue()], [tf.int32])
queue2_dequeue = tf.train.batch([call_func], batch_size=3, shapes=[[]], enqueue_many=True)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
try:
  while True:
    print sess.run(queue2_dequeue)
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
  pass
finally:
  coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

You should see

```
[0 0 1]
[0 0 1]
```

Comment: One more thing. I understand what the example is doing but I am missing the 'label part'. How do I merge/join each label to a sequence? Each variable length output of `py_func` should be paired with its label when input into `tf.train.batch()`. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there still no better solution than this?